# What is the story about Oracle CREATE TRIGGER ... CALL syntax?

Tags: oracle, trigger

I was able to use the CREATE TRIGGER ... CALL SOMEPROCEDURE; syntax but I'm a little bewildered about it.  I expected to see some implicit arguments like TABLE%ROWTYPE new but that doesn't seem to be the case.

The documentation doesn't mention this at all.

In a two-year-old post some stackexchangers call the construct "paleolithic."  Is it really that worthless?  Was there anything such a trigger was ever able to do?  Or is there a form with arguments and context and such?

Comment: CALL procedure is documented in the manual. You can pass necessary parameters to the procedure IF the procedure needs it. In your case, it sounds like it may not. I don't think there is anything wrong in using procedures vs actual code in trigger body, you choose what works for you.

Comment: ... :-/  I didn't find CALL documented in the 11gR2 docset, only the one comment in the CREATE TRIGGER pieces of the SQL and PL/SQL references. I was able to use CALL on a proc without parameters but that's a little pointless.  I thought it might support a 'blind' interface like DBMS_RLS policy functions.